# Handling character strings in R - 'Word formatted' lists

Tags: regex, r, plyr

With a few exceptions one will find lists of species (particularly bird species) in Word (.doc) documents and quite often they will be structured in a fashion that is useless for data analysis of any kind.

Lists will be something like this, with spaces and everything else:
It includes the Taxonomy (Family) and species with common and scientific name.

## The data

```
1 STRUTHIONIDAE (1)
Common Ostrich Struthio camelus


2 DIOMEDEIDAE (5 – 1 + 1)

++Northern Royal Albatross Diomedea sanfordi

Black-browed Albatross Thalassarche melanophris

Shy Albatross Thalassarche cauta

Grey-headed Albatross Thalassarche chrysostoma

Atlantic Yellow-nosed Albatross Thalassarche chlororhynchos


3 Procellaridae (11 – 1 + 1)

Southern Giant Petrel Macronectes giganteus

Pintado Petrel Daption capense

Great-winged Petrel Pterodroma macroptera

Soft-plumaged Petrel Pterodroma mollis

Antarctic Prion Pachyptila desolata

White-chinned Petrel Procellaria aequinoctialis

++Spectacled Petrel Procellaria conspicillata

Cory's Shearwater Calonectris [diomedea] borealis

Great Shearwater Puffinus gravis

Sooty Shearwater Puffinus griseus

Manx Shearwater Puffinus puffinus


4 HYDROBATIDAE (3)

Wilson's Storm-Petrel Oceanites oceanicus

British Storm-Petrel Hydrobates pelagicus

Leach's Storm-Petrel Oceanodroma leucorhoa
```

Lists like this one are a extraordinary source of information for technical reports, design of geographical distributions, regional conservation status, summaries, etc.
This is of particular interest for regions where little is available or published (The example above is part the bird list of Angola from www.birdsangola.org).
The data will be better used if properly formatted. A dataframe will be a good candidate for any subsequent analysis over the data.

I would like to convert the list above into something usable, extracting species common names, scientific names and taxonomic families. A data.frame would be a good, natural candidate.

Comment: I can't see the question, I suggest you to repost this leaving the question and moving the answer in the answer section to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

#### before running this code copy the data above to the clipboard.

## R Code:

```
library(stringr)
# Read from clipboard (blank.lines.skip = T)
orig.list <- read.delim2('clipboard', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
l.species <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(orig.list)) {
  tmp.string <- unlist(str_extract_all(orig.list[i, ], "[A-Za-z]+"))
  l.species[i, 1] <- ifelse(length(tmp.string) == 1, tmp.string,
                            paste(tmp.string[1:(length(tmp.string)-2)],
                                  collapse = ' '))
  l.species[i, 2] <- paste(tmp.string[(length(tmp.string) - 1) : length(tmp.string)],
                           collapse = ' ')
  l.species[i, 3]<-ifelse(length(tmp.string) == 1, 1, 0)
}
names(l.species) <- c('common name', 'species', 'is.family')
taxon.family <- toupper(subset(l.species, is.family == 1,
                               select = species)$species)
rows.family <- as.numeric(row.names(subset(l.species, is.family == 1)))
l.species$family <- rep(taxon.family, times = diff(c(rows.family,
                                                     nrow(l.species)+1)))
l.spec.family <- subset(l.species, is.family == 0, select = -is.family)
```

## The resulting object:

```
> head(l.spec.family)                            
                      common name                     species        family
2                  Common Ostrich            Struthio camelus STRUTHIONIDAE
4        Northern Royal Albatross           Diomedea sanfordi   DIOMEDEIDAE
5          Black browed Albatross    Thalassarche melanophris   DIOMEDEIDAE
6                   Shy Albatross          Thalassarche cauta   DIOMEDEIDAE
7           Grey headed Albatross    Thalassarche chrysostoma   DIOMEDEIDAE
8 Atlantic Yellow nosed Albatross Thalassarche chlororhynchos   DIOMEDEIDAE
```

## A summary (for the entire data set with 941 species)

```
library(plyr)
summary.nesp <- ddply(l.spec.family, .(family), summarise,
                      prop_esp = length(family)/nrow(*all.data*)*100)
top.summary.nesp <- head(summary.nesp[order(summary.nesp$prop_esp, decreasing = T),], 6)

> top.summary.nesp
          family prop_esp
79     SYLVIIDAE 8.076514
1   ACCIPITRIDAE 5.419766
48    PASSERIDAE 5.100956
24   ESTRILDIDAE 4.250797
83      TURDIDAE 3.613177
44 NECTARINIIDAE 3.506908
```